# StreamReader 'strange' results

Tags: c#, json, httpwebrequest, streamreader

I have an SSIS job using a Script Component to calling a Web API with HttpWebRequest, using StreamReader to obtain a json result (array).

This was working fine, but after some new data was entered into the remote system, my job started failing.
TBH I was suspecting some special characters, but I've failed to find anything such.

Here's my tests to date...

(a) After obtaining the response, I cut the string to obtain just the first item in the array - for easier debugging. I then spat out the asciibytes to see exactly what was in there.

Using this string, my serializer fails.

So then I then added code at (b).
This is a hard coded string, and I spat to asciibytes to compare to the (a) above - and they are exactly the same.
Yet with this hard coded value, the serializer works and code completes with a smile.

What am I missing ??
(Please!)

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                {
                    jsonString = reader.ReadToEnd(); //.Replace("\\", "");
                    reader.Close();
                }
                jsonString = jsonString.Replace("\\", "");

                //-- TEST ------------------------------------------------
                // (a) cut array to first item only
                int itest = jsonString.IndexOf("},{");
                string stest = jsonString.Substring(0,itest) + "}]";
                byte[] asciiBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(stest);

                // (b) hard code the known json string
                jsonString = "[{\"custom_fields\":[],\"data_type\":\"smallint\",\"description\":\"\",\"ds_id\":2,\"db_comment\":null,\"id\":593163,\"is_primary_key\":false,\"is_foreign_key\":false,\"name\":\"fldno\",\"nullable\":false,\"schema_id\":3,\"table_id\":45906,\"table_name\":\"rr1.rr1.macob\",\"title\":\"Length, position in list, etc.\",\"position\":5,\"url\":\"/attribute/593163/\"}]";
                asciiBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(jsonString);
                //--- END TEST ------------------------------------------------

                JavaScriptSerializer sr = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                jsonResponse = sr.Deserialize<Datum[]>(jsonString);
```

Comment: Please print out `BitConverter.ToString(asciiBytes)` for the first one, and add the result to your question

Comment: What does the actual original JSON look like that is causing the failure?  And what is the actual code that it fails on?  And what is the actual error you are getting?  If you could include a [mre] in your question, that would be most helpful.   A couple of observations: (1) you shouldn't be needing to remove backslashes before deserializing.  If you find you are needing to do that, you may have double-serialized JSON.  (2) you should be using UTF8 encoding with JSON, not ASCII.

Comment: Brian, your point(1) was on the nail, once I removed it everything ran smoothly. Another case of not seeing the wood for the trees I think ! Thanks for your observations. If you want to post as an answer I will gladly attribute it.